# ansible: `cd: too many arguments`

Tags: bash, jenkins, ansible

I am trying to add new section in our ansible playbook which is run via Jenkins. I am error as `cd: too many arguments`.

ansible playbook code

```
- name: "obfuscating python code"
  command: "cd /opt/company_name/{{ app_name }}/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/{{ app_module }}/ & pyarmor obfuscate --src='.' -r __init__.py & cp -r dist/* . & rm -rf dist & cd -"
```

jenkins running ansible playbook is errored out like this

```
TASK [python-app : obfuscating python code] ************************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["cd", "/opt/company_name/app-name/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/app_name/", "&", "pyarmor", "obfuscate", "--src=.", "-r", "__init__.py", "&", "cp", "-r", "dist/*", ".", "&", "rm", "-rf", "dist", "&", "cd", "-"], "delta": "0:00:00.005432", "end": "2022-04-14 23:02:46.568316", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-04-14 23:02:46.562884", "stderr": "/bin/cd: line 2: cd: too many arguments", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/cd: line 2: cd: too many arguments"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

UPDATE: I updated code as suggested along with more commands I would like to have python virtual env activated before I run the pyarmor, it's now failing with `No such file or directory: 'source'`

```
- name: "obfuscating python code"
  command: "source /opt/company_name/{{ app_name }}/current/bin/activate && pyarmor obfuscate --src='.' -r __init__.py && cp -fr dist/* . && rm -rf dist"
  chdir: /opt/intuitive/{{ app_name }}/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/{{ app_module }}/
```

```
TASK [python-app : obfuscating python code] ************************************
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "source /opt/company/app-name/current/bin/activate '&&' pyarmor obfuscate --src=. -r __init__.py '&&' cp -fr 'dist/*' . '&&' rm -rf dist", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source': 'source'", "rc": 2}
```

Comment: It looks like Ansible is parsing the command and trying to execute it directly, rather than handing it off to a shell to run.  The shell would have split that into multiple commands at the `&` characters, but Ansible's message suggests that it is treating those as ordinary arguments.  You could likely invoke a shell explicitly in the command, but maybe someone more familiar with Ansible can suggest an easier way.  (Incidentally, from the perspective of shell input, it looks like you meant `&&` in each of the places where you wrote `&`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to use shell features with the `command` module. `command` does not use a shell, so your entire command line is passed to `cd` as arguments. You should instead use the `shell` module when you use shell features like pipelines, file globbing, etc.

You can also use the module's built-in support for setting the working directory to make your command a little shorter.

```yaml
- name: Obfuscate python code
  shell: 
    cmd: pyarmor obfuscate --src='.' -r __init__.py && cp -r dist/* . && rm -rf dist
    chdir: /opt/company_name/{{ app_name }}/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/{{ app_module }}
```

Comment: please see my updated questions, it has new errors

Comment: You are still trying to use the `command` module, but passing it a command that requires shell features. Use the `shell` module. (Your use of chdir is also incorrect; please actually look at the code in the answer.)